# Ways to get id to use in modal for updating database in php

Tags: php, html, ajax

So my purpose is to get the ID from a database and making the id ready to be used for modal. I know that I can use `input type=hidden` but I don't know for sure it is safe because in inspect element, user can edit it. I'm thinking also of `session` but I don't have any idea how can I do it. So what are the ways I can do to make the id not editable after submitting? Or how can i put it in array and match the id? Here is my code I used

class.names.php

```
public function getAllNames()
{
  $obj = new Db();
  $stmt = $obj->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM persons");
  while ($person = $stmt->fetch())
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$person['first_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$person['last_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a id=\"".$person['person_id']."\"type=\"button\" data-target-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#edit-name-modal\" class=\"btn btn-danger edit_data\" href=\"#\">Update</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
  }
}
```

names.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
 var person_id = $(this).attr("id");
 $.ajax({  
      url:"/data/updatename.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{person_id:person_id},
      dataType:"json",  
      success:function(data){
        $('#first_name').val(data.first_name);
        $('#last_name').val(data.last_name);
        $('#person_id').val(data.person_id);
        $('#edit-name-modal').modal('show');         
      }  
 });  
});
```

updatename.php

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';  
if(isset($_POST["person_id"]))  
{  
  $person_id = $_POST["person_id"]; 
  $object = new Dbc();
  $stmt = $object->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE person_id=?");
   $stmt->execute([$person_id]);  
  $profile_info = $stmt->fetch();
  echo json_encode($profile_info);    
}
?>
```

namelist.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-name-modal" name="edit-name" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="namelist.php">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Name's List</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="person_id" name="person_id">

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Its safe until you allow anyone to edit any users name.

Comment: does encrypting the id of the hidden type value advisable? that is the only way I know that it will make a secure data.

Comment: From this code, looks like you have no control, no login, no control over who uses your app. So anyone can edit anything. So you dont need to care about securing ID...

Comment: It does. It is not necessary to just put all codes, just an specific to get the idea. Get it?

Comment: the updatename.php script should first check the value of person_id submitted from the browser, check the identity of the current logged in user, and check whether they are a valid user to access that data. That's the only way to provide security. The user will always be able to change the values in the HTML and code in the browser, if they want to. So your server's first job is always to validate the input. This is linked to what I wrote in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625252/encrypted-data-wont-decrypt-after-post-method-in-php

Comment: and then when a submission is made to namelist.php, the server should also check that the data coming from there is ok, and that the user has permission to alter the data associated with the submitted person_id. In other words, the server has to validate _every time_ the user inputs _anything_. It's perfectly possible to use a tool like PostMan to make HTTP requests and send data to your server without ever visiting your website in a browser, so please forget the idea that you can provide any security within the browser-side code.