# Encrypted data won't decrypt after $_POST method in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I found out that whenever I past the my value from a `selectbox`value to be encrypted and to send as `$_POST` method and decrypting it, the value is becoming `NULL` or don't have any value at all. Here is the code below. I am also using ajax code here but I don't think it is necessary because it passes the value. How do I solve this problem?

```
option.php
    $species1 = 'Ant';
    $species2 = "Man";

    $obj = new EncDecrypt();
    $species1Enc = $obj->encrypt_data($species1);
    $species2Enc = $obj->encrypt_data($species2);

    echo '<select id="species" name="species">';'
    echo '<option value='.$species1Enc.'>Ant</option>';
    echo "<option value=\"".$species2Enc."\">Man</option>";
    echo '</select>';'

encdecrypt.php
    Class EncDecrypt
    {
        public function encrypt_data($data)
        {
            $plaintext = $data;

                $password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
                $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
                $key = password_hash($password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH, ['cost' => 12]);
                $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

                $encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));

                return $encrypted;
            }

            public function decrypt_data($data)
            {
                $data = $data;

                $password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
                $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
                $key = password_hash($password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH, ['cost' => 12]);
                $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

                $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);       

                return $decrypted;
            }
    }

display.php 
  if(isset($_POST["species"]) && !empty($_POST['species']))  
  {  
    $decdata = new EncDecrypt();
    $decryptData = $decdata->decrypt_data($_POST['species']);

    echo "<h1>".$species."</h1>";
  }
```

Comment: The first question has to be why are you bothering to (try and) encrypt and decrypt IDs for a dropdownlist?? IDs are just IDs, they are essentially meaningless, what could possibly be the problem with printing them in the HTML? And what security do you imagine this encrypted string is giving you anyway? All you're doing is replacing one unique ID with another unique ID for the same item. I can't imagine what the use case for this could possibly be, can you explain what benefit it gives you?

Comment: the value in the dropdown list can be edit thru inspect element and so i want to encrypt it.. also Im gonna use it for updating the data in database and so it needs an ID to be encrypted. I'm quite new to web development so im paranoid in terms of security

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583100/ways-to-get-id-to-use-in-modal-for-updating-database-in-php?noredirect=1#comment88181153_50583100 I have a related question here. i do hope you can give an advice or tips because the system I am building is for a school

Comment: "the value in the dropdown list can be edit thru inspect element "...so can the encrypted string. So what help does that bring you? Ok it's harder to guess a valid value, but it's not impossible. Anyway if the user changed the ID in the dropdownlist to something which is not valid, or for which they do not have permission, your server should detect that when the form is submitted. Simply hiding the ID does not provide security, instead the server must **always** check and validate what the user is inputting. Encryption doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: Google "security by obscurity", some links e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity explain why it's not a good idea to rely on simply hiding your data as means of protection

Comment: In my link that I provided. What I advice can you give as I need to validate the Id that can be edit?. should i replace it with another unique user id?

Comment: Just use the database-generated ID in your dropdownilst and stop imagining you have to keep it secret. It's no problem for users to know all the possible IDs, as long you check every time they try to use one (by which I mean trying to access or change any data associated to that ID), that they are actually allowed to use it. Nothing is a secret on the web except the things which are on your server. So every time the user sends some input to the server, you must validate it against your security and business requirements.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson! I really appreciate it, I know now what should I do, I keep wasting my time with this encryption. I will find a way to validate the user ID in server side. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of typos with `'` trailing your `;` on `echo '<select id="species" name="species">';'` and `echo '</select>';'`

Then I don't fully understand why you are trying to encrypt your form data and what exactly you are trying to achive here.

Anyway to the technical part of your question on why the encryption-decryption part is not working:

First of all you are using `$key = password_hash($password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH, ['cost' => 12]);` which will create a different string everytime.

Change this to the following
`$key = hash('sha256', $password, true);`

Then `$iv` should be unique everytime you make a new encryption and must be passed somehow in your POST variable. A good way to generate $iv is to use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`

So in order to achive what i mentioned before you have to change your functions:

```
public function encrypt_data($data) {
    $plaintext = $data;
    $password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
    $method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $key = hash('sha256', $password, true);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext, $key, true);

    return $iv . $hash . $ciphertext;
}

public function decrypt_data($data) {
    $ivHashCiphertext = $data;
    $password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
    $method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $iv = substr($ivHashCiphertext, 0, 16);
    $hash = substr($ivHashCiphertext, 16, 32);
    $ciphertext = substr($ivHashCiphertext, 48);
    $key = hash('sha256', $password, true);

    if (hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext, $key, true) !== $hash) return null;

    return openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}
```

Finaly you need to use `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` when you call your `encrypt_data` and `decrypt_data()` functions

`$species1Enc = base64_encode($obj->encrypt_data($species1));`

`$species2Enc = base64_encode($obj->encrypt_data($species2));`

`$decryptData = $decdata->decrypt_data(base64_decode($_POST['species']));`

Comment: This solves my problem! thank you very much for your time, but as ADyson says I need to validate the user input in the server side. I will keep this in mind thank you again!

Comment: Yeah as i said i didn't know what were you trying to achive coz it didn't make a lot of sense, i just pointed out why your code was not working as you expected. :)